# AngularJS Trouble with provider

Tags: angularjs

Hey guys I just put together a toggle with some animations in my AngularJS project. the sidebar that is being toggled is in a directive with a restriction of E. It works fine locally but when I put the application online I got this error.

```
    Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: eProvider <- e
    http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.0/$injector/unpr?p0=eProvider%20%3C-%20e
    at vendor-db22f3941a.js:11307
    at vendor-db22f3941a.js:15636
    at Object.r [as get] (vendor-db22f3941a.js:15789)
    at vendor-db22f3941a.js:15641
    at r (vendor-db22f3941a.js:15789)
    at i (vendor-db22f3941a.js:15813)
    at Object.a [as invoke] (vendor-db22f3941a.js:15835)
    at f.instance (vendor-db22f3941a.js:21094)
    at $ (vendor-db22f3941a.js:20166)
    at vendor-db22f3941a.js:20470(anonymous function) @ vendor-db22f3941a.js:24475
```

Am I supposed to use a different restriction on directives if I am trying to animate them?

Here is my code

Directive

```
(function() {'use strict';

  angular
    .module('bhamDesign')
    .directive('bhamSidebar', bhamSidebar);

  function bhamSidebar(){
    var directive = {
      restrict: 'E',
      templateUrl: 'app/components/sidebar/sidebar.html',
      controller: bhamSidebarController
    };

    return directive;
  }

  function bhamSidebarController($scope){
    var vm = $scope;

    vm.toggle = false;

    vm.toggleSidebar = function () {
        vm.toggle=!vm.toggle;
    };
  }

})();
```

HTML View

```
#sidebar-wrapper(ng-class="{'open': toggle}")
  .toggle-box(ng-click="toggleSidebar()")
    span
    span
    span
  img(src="assets/images/about.jpg")
```

Comment: You're most probably minifying your JavaScript code, but don't do [what it takes](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di#dependency-annotation) to make your AngularJS code minifiable. Use ng-annotate.

Comment: If that doesn't work please provide a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) because your code looks fine so far

Comment: I'm using gulp to compile and minify them, it has worked fine up until this point with all other controllers and directives but once I started using animations that things got tripped up and everything on the site still works besides the animation of toggling the side bar in and out of view. It does look like a problem with my minification but I'm curious why it would trigger at this point. I'll try put a MCVE together a little later. Thanks guys!

Comment: It's not a problem with the minification. It's a problem with your code not being minifiable. Look at your posted controller: you're not using $inject, and you're not using the array notation, and there is no ngInject annotation that could be used by ngAnnotate.

Comment: Got it, you were a hundred percent correct JB Nizet I used a generator to scaffold my project and I just went back and looked at the original projects directive set up. It looks like you need a ng-inject when you use a directive and controller in the same file?